# "put your coat on" and "put on your coat" but not "depend on someone" and "depend someone on*"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, word-order

Why can you say
"put on your coat" and "put your coat on"
but not
"depend on someone" and "depend someone on*"?

Why are adverbs ("on" in the first sentence) mobile, whereas prepositions ("on" in the second sentence) have a fixed position?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. It's exactly that; they're prepositions and not an adverbial particle linked to the verb. An adposition is always in a fixed position with respect to its complement.

Comment: @Ledda: So _by_ in the inseparable _come by_ (_he came by some money_) is a preposition rather than a particle? Not so. It's far more closely bound to the simplex verb, in a MWV structure, just like _on_ in _put on_ (= don). It's very hard to explain why some of these MWVs are separable while others aren't. And, while we're on the subject, to determine the exact dividing line between MWVs and _verb + preposition_ constructions.

Comment: I don't understand, why is it not just a verb that is frozen to require a specific prepositional phrase?

Comment: In phrasal verbs, a distinction is sometimes made between prepositions and postpositions (adverbs, in fact). For example in 'get away with it', 'away' is an adverb or postposition, whereas 'with' is a preposition. The unexpressed complement of the adverb is 'away from the unpleasant situation you are in'. Again, the adverb is a kind of preposition or prepositional phrase which 'carries its complement with itself', which explains its mobility.

Comment: MWV is mutli-words verbs.

Comment: I was always under the impression that phrasal verbs are a remnant of separable verbs in Germanic languages. How is "depend on" any different to "wait for"?

Comment: The adverb 'away' does not come before the pronoun 'it' because it does not have to, contrary to the preposition 'with'.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean "get away with it". In that construction, isn't it analysed as "get away" being the phrasal verb, the verb being intransitive, and then requiring the prepositional phrase "with x"?

Comment: @Ledda: Phrasal verbs are constructions evolved along the same lines as German trennbare Vorsilben, but they're not necessarily cognate.

Answer (score 3):

Macmillan says that **depend on** is a [transitive phrasal verb](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/depend-on) (I'd use the term transitive multi-word verb, MWV).

Certainly, **put on** as used here, meaning 'don', is a transitive MWV. This is not always the case for 'put on'; [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94326/is-on-part-of-a-verb-phrase-in-put-item-on-hold/94338#94338) is a discussion arguing that in

> put on weight

put on is a MWV, whereas in

> put on hold

put is a simplex verb followed by the prepositional phrase 'on hold'.

Once we've decided (assuming we do) that we're dealing with MWVs here, we can drop any mention of adverbs and prepositions, because behaviour of particles may well differ from how adverbs and prepositions behave, especially with regard to distribution (where they may be placed in a sentence).

Some transitive MWVs are separable:

> Put your coat on / Put on your coat /// Turn the light off / Turn off
>   the light

and some aren't (or the jury is out):

> How did he come by the money /// You can count on her  /// This calls
>   for wisdom /// ?gives off a gas

It may well be that the particles in the non-separable constructions have migrated further from any original individual meaning, so they are even more tightly bound to their simplex verbs (to create new lexemes) than those in separable constructions.

Comment: Yup. Those transitivizing prepositions, like the _at_ of _look at him_, are in the process of becoming clitics and/or suffixes ("lookit him" in eye dialect), and they're spread all over the separability spectrum. [My favorite here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/EnglishPhrasalVerbs.pdf) is _run over_.

Answer (score 0):

Adverbs are a kind of preposition which carries with itself the name or ponoun it introduces:

so, "put your coat on" is like "put your coat on (yourself/your body)", "put on your coat" is like "put on (yourself/your body) your coat".

I would say an adverb is a preposition followed by a noun or pronoun which is not expressed, which is understood. That is the reason why they can be found in different positions, there is nothing in the sentence that they need to introduce, to precede.

Same thing with conjunctions, which introduce/precede a clause, compulsory front-position, whereas adverbs meaning the same can be found in front-, mid-, or end-position.

"There is sun **but** the weather is not very warm."

"There is sun. **However**, the weather is not very warm. / The weather, **however**, is not very warm. / The weather is not very warm, **however**."

The adverb 'however' means the same as 'in spite of this' (in spite of = prepositional phrase + this = pronoun representing the first clause/sentence, the fact that 'There is sun.')

It is because the adverb 'however' carries the first clause/sentence with itself that it can come in different positions, which the coordination conjunction 'but' cannot do.

Comment: And I would say that an adverb is _not_ "a preposition followed by a noun or pronoun which is not expressed", though there are words which can serve as either a preposition or an adverb. What is the preposition and the unexpressed noun which are _quickly_, or _quite_, or _again_?

Comment: I find the knee-jerk reaction of native speakers of English against any attempt to rationalize their language (for the sake of learning it better, because we love it) unsettling!

Comment: How else can you explain the mobility of the adverb as opposed to the fixedness of prepositions and conjunctions?

Comment: Those pseudo-rules are short-cuts to mastering your language… but it looks like only circuitous ways will do. If it takes the native speaker of any language fifteen to twenty years to master their mother tongue, why should any foreigner be bold enough to assume they can achieve the same results in less time!

Comment: I explain the mobility by noting that a preposition introduces a PP (prepositional phrase), which requires a NP (noun phrase) as its head; but an adverb doesn't. It is true that adverbs and PP's generally occur in the same places, and that some adverbs can be replaced by a PP with similar meaning; but claiming that an adverb is a preposition whose NP is not expressed is simply false.

Answer (score -2):

That's because prepositions are positioned "pre" (= before) the word they refer to.

Comment: Is that always true?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, it should.

Comment: So why did you write 'That's because prepositions are positioned "pre" (= before) the word they refer **to**.'? (Since that might be analysed as a particle, I'll just add 'Prepositions are words we may end sentences with.').

Comment: Because @user58319 asked why adverbs are mobile while prepositions are fixed. So by explaining why prepositions are fixed I hoped to show him/her the difference between prepositions and adverbs.

Comment: I'll speak plainly. Prepositions do **not** always have to be placed before the noun group they are associated with.

Comment: "The noun group with which they are associated, dear Edwin". ;o)

Comment: I'm thinking of a withering riposte.

Comment: 'before the word they refer to' is a re-ordering of 'before the word to which they refer', with the preposition 'to' BEFORE the relative pronoun 'which', which represents 'the word'.

Comment: @user58319 So if re-orderings are sometimes permissible, one can't accept 'That's because prepositions are positioned "pre" (= before) the word they refer to' as valid reasoning for lack of mobility.